# Too many Try Catch block experience a slow performance? Any alternative solution?

Tags: asp.net, oop, c#-4.0, try-catch

I was developing a website by using c# with .net framework 4. OO concepts have been implemented. Each layer has some Try Catch blocks used to handle different errors and return different error messages. I found that it getting slower when loading as the try catch block getting more and more. I wonder this is because why. Any alternative solution? Correct me if I am wrong. Appreciate for any reply.

Comment: Sounds like you have good, quality code and you observe a performance issue in an 'exceptional' case.  If it's exceptional/rare to the user, then perhaps it doesn't matter in the big scheme of things that the error path is slow?

Comment: You need to also make sure that you are not throwing a bunch of strong typed exceptions from inside other try/catch's (this could also be an issue). Instead just use throw. Also using CustomExceptions could help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using try/catch blocks. They don't alter performance. what does alter performance is throwing errors!

see web site below particularly:

> Throwing exceptions can be very expensive, so make sure that you don't
>   throw a lot of them. Use Perfmon to see how many exceptions your
>   application is throwing. It may surprise you to find that certain
>   areas of your application throw more exceptions than you expected. For
>   better granularity, you can also check the exception number
>   programmatically by using Performance Counters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Exception usually help us to handle the wrong initialization (creating the object with an invalid state) of an object because the constructor doesn't return any value or in the other case if we have an method which return an instance of an object which should never be null. So in case of constructor you could create an static method named getInstance which will return you the instance of your object or null in case of wrong initialization, make your constructors private in this case but exceptions are much better. In case of method which return an instance you could use the technique that COM technology use, by passing an reference to your boolean variable which will show you the execution result.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good [links](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/06/22/performance-implications-of-try-catch-finally.aspx) about try/catch and their cost. [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009.aspx) says that it can negatively affect performance.

I would review whether you are using exceptions for what they are really for, exceptional circumstances, and not for program flow. If they do affect program flow, then you're risking the possibility of side effects. MSDN states:

> Clean up intermediate results when throwing an exception. Callers
>   should be able assume that there are no side effects when an exception
>   is thrown from a method

If this is the case, then I would consider creating methods which return errors explicitly as/when necessary and handle this way instead.